# Send an invite from flutter app for new users to register for app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As a business owner, I want to be able to send my employees an invitation to register to use my flutter app. I want to do this from within my app.

I am thinking about having a screen where I enter an email address or phone number and send an invitation link to the registration screen. When the user clicks on the link they are taken to the registration screen where they can fill in their email and password and register via Firebase Authentication.

How do I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Easy. Hire Developer and you done